# JSON interface with UNIX

Tags: json, unix

Am very new to JSON interaction, I have few doubts regarding it. Below are the basic one

1) How could we call/invoke/open JSON file through Unix, I mean let suppose I have a metedata file in JSON, then how should I fetch/update the value backforth from JSON file.

2) Need the example, on how to interact it.

3) How Unix Shell is compatible to JSON, whether is there any other tech/language/tool which is better than shell script.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: The basic requirement in my project is that, I am using Shell script to extract data form files, tables and landing all to Local filesystem. So current I just stored the metedata for those files, tables in a file (.txt) format. Now I have to store thsoe metadata in JSON format, which is compatible to many other utilities. So need to know how I can achive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json is a format to store *strings*, *bools*, *numbers*, *lists*, and *dicts* and combinations thereof (*dicts* of *numbers* pointing to *lists* containing *strings* etc.).  Probably the data you want to store has some kind of structure which fits into these types.  Consider that and think of a valid representation using the types given above.

For example, if your text configuration looks something like this:

```
Section
  Name=Marsoon
  Size=34
  Contents
    foo
    bar
    bloh
  EndContents
EndSection

Section
  Name=Billition
  Size=103
  Contents
    one
    two
    three
  EndContents
EndSection
```

… then this looks like a *list* of *dicts* which contain some *strings* and *numbers* and one *list* of *strings*.  A valid representation of that in Json would be:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Marsoon",
    "Size": 34,
    "Contents": [
      "foo", "bar", "bloh"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Billition",
    "Size": 103,
    "Contents": [
      "one", "two", "three"
    ]
  },
]
```

But in case you *know* that each such dictionary has a different `Name` and always the same fields, you don't have to store the field names and can use the `Name` as a key of a dictionary; so you can also represent it as a *dict* of *strings* pointing to *lists* containing *numbers* and *lists* of *strings*:

```
{
  "Marsoon": [
    34, [ "foo", "bar", "bloh" ]
  ],
  "Billition": [
    103, [ "one", "two", "three" ]
  ]
}
```

Both are valid representations of your original text configuration.  How you'd choose depends mainly on the question whether you want to stay open for later changes of the data structure (the first solution is better then) or if you want to avoid bureaucratic overhead.

Such a Json can be stored as a simple text file.  Use any text editor you like for this.  Notice that all whitespace is optional.  The last example could also be written in one line:

```
{"Marsoon":[34,["foo","bar","bloh"]],"Billition":[103,["one","two","three"]]}
```

So sometimes a computer-generated Json might be hard to read and would need an editor at least capable of handling very long lines.

*Handling* such a Json file in a shell script will not be easy just because the shell has no notion of the idea of such complex types.  The most complicated it can handle properly is a *dict* of *strings* pointing to *strings* (bash arrays).  So I propose to have a look for a more suitable language, e. g. Python.  In Python you can handle all these structures quite efficiently and with very readable code:

```
import json

with open('myfile.json') as jsonFile:
  data = json.load(jsonFile)

print data[0]['Contents'][2]  # will print "bloh" in the first example
   # or:
print data['Marsoon'][1][2]  # will print "bloh" in the second example
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is *just text* [following a specific format](http://json.org).

Use a text editor and follow the rules. Some editors with "JSON modes" will help with [invalid] syntax highlighting, indenting, brace matching..

A "Unix Shell" has nothing directly to do with JSON - how does a shell relate to text or XML files?

There are some utilities for dealing with JSON which might be of use such as [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) - but it really depends on *what* needs to be done with the JSON (which is ultimately *just text*).

Comment: The basic requirement in my project is that, I am using Shell script to extract data form files, tables and landing all to Local filesystem. So current I just stored the metedata for those files, tables in a file (.txt) format. Now I have to store thsoe metadata in JSON format, which is compatible to many other utilities. So need to know how I can achive this

Comment: @user3205631 Then go find the [individual] tools or utilities that are required to accomplish the task(s). At some point it might be easier just to use a language with JSON and dynamic structure support (e.g. Perl, Ruby, Python, TCL) instead of doing everything in "Unix Shell".

Comment: At quite an early point it **will** be easier to just use a language :)